# ER=EPR, Entanglement and Subjectivity

Tags: quantum-entanglement, quantum-interpretations, wormholes, quantum-teleportation

[ER=EPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ER%3DEPR) refers to a conjectured connection between entanglement and Einstein-Rosen bridges.

Consider the quantum teleportation circuit, where Alice ($A$) and Bob ($B$) make use of an entangled pair of qubits to transport a state from Alice's location to Bob's location.

Once Alice measures her state, *both Alice's and Bob's state collapse to a basis state.*

Suppose Alice and Bob are spatially separated. The resolution of EPR here, is that Bob cannot know the transported state until a *bit* is sent to his location.

- At the '**subjective**' level, nothing strange has happened. Information has not been transmitted faster than the speed of light, since the requirement of sending a bit constrains the system to observing the cosmic speed limit $c$.
- If we take physical reality to be '**objective**', then something 'illegal' is happening: measurement instantly affects two separated qubits (information travels from $A$ to $B$ with infinite speed).

> **(Q1)** Is this summary correct? I.e. the above resolution is an example of how QM can be interpreted as positing that reality must be observer-based.

In the subjective instance, the immediate collapse of both states is an abstraction in the total Hilbert space of the system. The bit being sent from $A$ to $B$ is our key to accessing the information in the joint Hilbert space.

> **(Q2)** Is the proposition *ER=EPR* a way of allowing us to reassume the 'objective' reality stance? I.e. that the instant collapse is a physical part of reality, and that this is made possible by an ER-bridge connecting $A$ and $B$.

In summary, it seems like without ER=EPR, we have to take the 'subjective stance' (things are only 'physically real' if we can observe them). If ER=EPR, then reality could still be objective (immediate collapse happens, independently of Alice/Bob's observation). I just wanted to check that these thoughts were in order.

Comment: Distances by themselves aren't "spacelike". Only _intervals between events_ can be spacelike. If Alice and Bob are separated by some distance, then the interval between their measurements can be spacelike, timelike, or lightlike, depending on how much time passes between the measurements.

Comment: Also, note that wavefunction collapse is not an integral part of quantum mechanics, but rather an artifact of the Copenhagen Interpretation (and some others). There are interpretations that do away with it entirely, like decoherence-based interpretations.

Comment: The two events will **not** always be causally disconnected _unless_ Alice and Bob make their measurements at _exactly the same time_. Any time difference between their measurements $\Delta t$, no matter how small, imposes a minimum separation distance for the events to be spacelike separated $d=c\Delta t$. For example, if they can synchronize their measurements to be within a nanosecond of each other, they must be 30 cm apart for their measurements to be spacelike separated.

Comment: @probably_someone Yeah, woops. Do we have to account for the notion of simultaneity from SR? Got it.

Comment: The time interval between measurements will be different in different reference frames, as will the observed distance between the measurements. What will _not_ change is the spacetime interval between the measurements, which is what determines the spacelike/timelike/lightlike character of the separation. That quality is Lorentz-invariant. Keep in mind, however, that quantum mechanics (as opposed to QFT) is explicity _not_ Lorentz-invariant, so trying to combine it and special relativity may lead to problems.

Comment: @probably_someone Thanks, I've edited the question.